# Excel functions to C# code

Tags: c#, .net, excel

So I'm trying to convert this Excel cell calculation into C#, but I can't really make sense of what it's doing. I read over the `EDATE` definition and it still doesn't make too much sense.

```
IF(EDATE(B25,-12)>A25,((EDATE(B25,-12)-A25)/(EDATE(B25,-12)-EDATE(EDATE(B25,-12),-12)))+1,(B25-A25)/(B25-EDATE(B25,-12)))

B25 = End Date
A25 = Start Date
```

It's essentially trying to calculation a fraction of a year. Should be very easy to do, but I'm not entirely sure what this `EDATE` thing does.

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/edate-HP005209073.aspx this link will explain what EDATE is in Excel

Comment: ... from which it's clear `EDATE` is `DateTime.AddMonths()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [EDATE](http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/excel-2010-edate-function/), you're mostly dealing with `12 months before the End Date (B25)`.

Given that, this seems to say:

**If the start date is more than 12 months before the end date then:**

**(The amount of time that the start date is prior to the year before the end date divided by one year) + 1**

**Else:**

**The amount of time that the start date is prior to the end date divided by one year.**

I *really* don't know how Excel handles date arithmetic or what the point of this function is, but that's my pseudo at a glance.

Really, it's just checking the `if` condition I mentioned, then offsetting the entire arithmetic by a year if the condition is true.

---

**Edit**

Okay, some quick research shows that Excel does date arithmetic purely as days, so then `12/1/1900 - 1/1/1900 = 335` days.  Putting a time on either date makes it a fraction of a day.

Given that, this Excel formula appears to attempt to calculate the fractional year difference between the two dates.

This is a rough piece of code that should provide it:

```
TimeSpan span = endDate.Subtract(startDate);
double years = span.Days / 365.25;
```

Comment: This is great, thanks so much for your help. But what if some years have 366 days and others have 365. The 365.25 would be trying to even that out, however, what if the difference is say between 5/26/2011 and 6/2/2012?

Comment: Would something like this work? `toDate.Subtract(new DateTime(toDate.Year - 1, toDate.Month, toDate.Day)).Days` as far as the denominator goes, but use the `Subtract` to get the numerator.

Comment: @slandau: that is closer to the original and better if your goal is to come up with the same answer as Excel. I'm not sure it's the _right_ answer though. What if the `toDate`'s year doesn't encompass Feb 29, but the difference between `startDate` and `toDate` does encompass a leap year? Suddenly, you're off again.  So, the answer to your question is, what is the requirement? Hope that helped.